# How to remove a namespace reference in a saved .rda object in R?

Tags: r, namespaces

I've got a package with a data object (.rda) that was originally created by another package and seems to have a reference to its original namespace.

The man page for `load()` explains:

> Objects can be saved with references to namespaces, usually as part of
>   the environment of a function or formula. As from R 3.1.0 such objects
>   can be loaded even if the namespace is not available: it is replaced
>   by a reference to the global environment with a warning. The warning
>   identifies the first object with such a reference (but there may be
>   more than one).

I need to remove this reference, as it is causing warnings to be thrown during package checks.   I've tried just loading and re-saving the object but don't see how to modify the namespace.  Any suggestions?

Edit:

The object is a 'network'.  I haven't figured out another example, but should be able to reproduce the same example:

```
install.packages('ndtv')
library(ndtv)
loadedNamespaces()
[1] "animation"      "base"           "datasets"       "graphics"      
[5] "grDevices"      "methods"        "ndtv"           "network"       
[9] "networkDynamic" "sna"            "statnet.common" "stats"         
[13] "tools"          "utils"
data(msm.sim)
loadedNamespaces()
[1] "animation"      "base"           "datasets"       "ergm"          
[5] "graphics"       "grDevices"      "methods"        "ndtv"          
[9] "network"        "networkDynamic" "sna"            "statnet.common"
[13] "stats"          "tools"          "utils"
```

notice the addition of the 'ergm' namespace

Comment: Can you create // provide a reproducible example?

Comment: What is the class of the object ?

Comment: the object is a 'network'.  I haven't figured out another example, but should be able to reproduce the same example:
    install.packages('ndtv')
    library(ndtv)
    namespacesLoaded()
    data(msm.sim)
    namespacesLoaded()

notice the addition of the 'ergm' namespace

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374680/can-i-load-an-rdata-file-while-bypassing-loading-the-namespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've resolved this by creating a new network object, and copying each of the named elements of the `msm.sim` object over to the new object, then re-saving the new object over the old one.  Perhaps the namespace attachment was triggered by a function attached to `msm.sim` when it was generated by the ergm package so I don't see it when calling `edit()` on the object?  There must be a better way. I still think that if name-space triggering elements can be attached to an object, there should be function to list what they are and where they are attached.